# How to get per-page views from Google Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use the Google Reporting API and the Query building tool to get a report on page views per URL.

I have a simple blog (custom CMS, not wordpress) that I use to publish a bunch of posts every month. I want, in my dashboard to get a number (of pageviews) next to each post.

1. Is this possible?
2. Does this require that I create a custom dimension in GA, if yes, which one is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible (especially if you do not need realtime data), but your question is rather broad - can you tell us what you have tried and where things started to go wrong for you ?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have used the Query Explorer to try and build a query that would give me views per page. I actually want a trend(?) of views per post over a period of one month, so I could use the datapoints to create a sparkline for each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have used the Query Explorer to try and build a query that would
>   give me views per page. I actually want a trend(?) of views per post
>   over a period of one month, so I could use the datapoints to create a
>   sparkline for each post

Select ga:date and ga:pagePath as dimensions and ga:pageviews as metric. Order by ga:pagePath. You do not need any custom dimensions.